# Date formatting error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, momentjs

I've written the following code to initialize jquery [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) with the current date in DD-MM-YY format, using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). However instead of the current date appearing, I'm seeing the value `03/08/1920`.

Console shows the value of curdate correctly: `Date is 27-08-18`.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    console.log('Loaded createbill.js');
    var curdate = moment().format('DD-MM-YY');
    console.log('Date is ' + curdate);

    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        format: 'dd-mm-yy',
        autoShow: true,
        showButtonPanel: true
    });
    $("#datepick").datepicker("setDate", curdate);
});
```

The html of the element is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepick" data-toggle="datepicker" required="" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  console.log('Loaded createbill.js');
  var curdate = moment().format('dd-mm-yy');
  console.log('Date is ' + curdate);

  $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    autoShow: true,
    showButtonPanel: true
  });

  $("#datepick").datepicker();

  $("#datepick").datepicker("setDate", new Date(curdate));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize the datepicker first, then call your datepicker `setDate` method.

```
$("#datepick").datepicker();

$("#datepick").datepicker("setDate", curdate);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8jav7tn/18/)

Comment: Even in your fiddle, the date format is not correct